# insert single integer as time function

Tags: asp.net, datetime, time

how to make the system to recognize even if i only input a single data for time? i want the user to be able to input a single number(2 or 3) and it will recognize it as 02:00 or 03:00. currently it work perfectly if the user insert 02 or 03.

```
starttime = DateTime.ParseExact(txtStart2.Text, "HH", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
endtime = DateTime.ParseExact(txtEnd2.Text, "HH", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Label3.Text = starttime.ToShortTimeString();
Label4.Text = endtime.ToShortTimeString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give single `"H"` instead of `"HH"` for hour to accept single digit hour.

```
starttime = DateTime.ParseExact(txtStart2.Text, "%H%", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

**Edit** If you give single digit for hour it is treated as datetime format not only hour.

> If the "h" format specifier is used without other custom format
>   specifiers, it is interpreted as a standard date and time format
>   specifier and throws a FormatException, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#hSpecifier).

To give single digit you have to modify the format string by adding spaces of % sign

> A custom date and time format string consists of two or more
>   characters. Date and time formatting methods interpret any
>   single-character string as a standard date and time format string. If
>   they do not recognize the character as a valid format specifier, they
>   throw a FormatException. For example, a format string that consists
>   only of the specifier "h" is interpreted as a standard date and time
>   format string. However, in this particular case, an exception is
>   thrown because there is no "h" standard date and time format
>   specifier. To use any of the custom date and time format specifiers as
>   the only specifier in a format string (that is, to use the "d", "f",
>   "F", "g", "h", "H", "K", "m", "M", "s", "t", "y", "z", ":", or "/"
>   custom format specifier by itself), include a space before or after
>   the specifier, or include a percent ("%") format specifier before the
>   single custom date and time specifier, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#hSpecifier).

Comment: Your code throws FormatException exception: Input string was not in a correct format..